# How to change default "sort by" to "type" in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

How to change the `sort by` for folders to `type`, because I want folders to be shown first and then files by name. When I sort by type, I get the result I want, but I need to change this for all my folders.

How can I change the `default preference` to `sort by: type`, so every folder will by default be sorted by type? I tried with `dconf-editor`, then `org > gnome > nautilus > preferences` and tried to choose `type` in `default-sort-order`, but I can only select `modification_date`, not by `type`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On Nemo (a recent fork of nautilus), I have the following in the menu :

1. `Edit > Preferences`
2. then on the `Views` tab

   - I got a section called `Default View`
   - with a line **Arrange items**, there is a select where I can choose the default sort order

#### Screenshot

[image: http://imgur.com/OO2lMIz]

Comment: It says installing Nemo will install Cinnamon too (http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-install-nemo-file-manager-in.html). I wouldn't like to change anything now, if there is a solution without changes :)

Comment: I never meant you to install `Nemo`, just show you the option exist in recent version. Which ubuntu and nautilus version do you use ? Add it to the question/description

Comment: got similar settings on a nautilus 3.4.2. Did you close your nautilus and open it back ?

Comment: Yes, I am a noob to the Ubuntu, sorry. I found the `preference > default view`. I didn't see it in the top bar, instead I was trying `dconf-editor` :(

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has been bugging me for a long time.. Why isn't this the default?!

Answer (score 17):

Determine the current default value of Nautilus sort order using `gsettings`

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order
```

Then change/set it to 'type'

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'type'
```

The change happens instantly

Comment: Change `type` to `mtime` to sort by Last Modified. You can also set `default-sort-in-reverse-order` to `true` to sort in reverse order.

Answer (score 13):

*update February 2017*:

nautilus now has a configuration option to sort directories first (I think since 3.14 or so) so I recommend using that instead of changing the default sort order. It is literally the first item in GUI preferences.

---

**initial post from May 2014**

I see the same problems on Fedora 18 (using the same versions).

The first attempt using dconf directly via the command line does not work for me:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/default-sort-order type
error: 0-4:unknown keyword
```

Now gsettings to the rescue:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order type
```

I'm not sure why dconf does not accept 'type' as a valid value even though dconf-editor explicitely lists it in the help text but gsettings works for me just fine.

Comment: Set by "modification time" using `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order mtime`

Comment: user274121 added this explanation: "the quotes need to be passed to dconf" so `dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/default-sort-order \'type\'` would be the correct call.

Comment: 2021 - None of the answers seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Change the reverse sort order settings for files(nautilus)/nemo on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep reverse
```

...

```
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences default-sort-in-reverse-order true    
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-in-reverse-order true
```

Answer (score 1):

In preferences -> Views -> **Arrange Items**

It has got 'By Type' in the drop down list.

If you can't see preferences in gnome-shell, click on the nautilus icon in the top panel

[image]