# Is there a way to manually organize the apps and folders in gnome application menu?

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I'm using 20.04 and I've seemed to have found an extension for pretty much everything I needed so far besides this. I would like to be able to drag and drop the app icons and folders in the application menu in any order that I want. I don't like that it mixes in folders and apps together because it just sorts alphabetically. Is there an extension or hack for this?

Comment: Doesn't sorting by 'Type' resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't see that as an option anywhere for the show applications menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to rename the folders. For example I have a folder called Utilities. After renaming it 1_Utilities, it's now the very first icon in the menu. You can rename the folders by right clicking on them.

[image]

Comment: Not a solution.Merely a valid workaround.

Comment: @vanadium and yet ironically similar to the accepted answer.

Comment: @vanadium OP flipped decision and accepted the answer you downvoted (I presume). Please give it a second judgement unless you have a better idea of course. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I was not the one that downvoted. Workarounds are sometimes the only option, like here.

Comment: I upvoted both suggestions. This approach allows full control on the order, so deserves to be the "accepted" answer, but the other suggestion indeed is very nice and elegant.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks for clearing the air. Unfortunately the only comment is often associated with the only downvote.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there are no true solutions to this problem so I just added brackets to my folder names and I got the desired result. Hopefully, the ability to drag and drop to manually re-order will be added in the future.

[image: screenshot]

Edit: as of 9/16 this has been added as a feature in gnome 3.38!

Comment: I wonder if a simple single space in front of the name would have accomplished the same?

Comment: Good idea, but I just gave it a shot and it ignores whitespace.

Comment: Well on the flip side the square brackets yell out to you: "THIS IS A FOLDER" :). Upvoting your Q&A as well as accepted answer that was down voted. Welcome to **Ask Ubuntu** and hope to see more of your good ideas in the future.

Comment: Well thank you for unlocking some new askubuntu privileges for me!

Comment: They are well deserved. You get 2 points by accepting an answer, 2 points for editing a question or answer (assuming your edit is accepted by peer-review) and as you've just learned 10 points for an up-voted question and 10 points for an up-voted answer. If your answer is accepted you get 15 points unless it is your own question in which case you get 0. Points gained on edits is limited to 2,000. Edits can be as simple as correcting a typo or removing extra sentence or as complicated as fix a slew of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your files by 'Type'.
I am assuming you use 'nautilus' the default file-manager for Ubuntu.
[Check this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/748260/498536).

To find out what file-manager you are using, run

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

If you have Nautilus installed, you will see something like

```
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

If not, you will see whatever file-manager you are using. Then use that information to search for

'Sort by type on [file-manager-name]'

Comment: I am using Nautilus, and running the following to sort by type has no effect on the application menu:

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order
'type'`

Comment: I also went into dconf editor to confirm and it is set to type. However, if I go into the file manager, the gui still sorts A-Z.

Comment: can you send a screenshot of your file manager with the 'sort by' options visible? If you cannot find those options, just send a screenshot with your file manager visible with all its toolbars.

Comment: [dconf](https://i.imgur.com/tckUUs8.png) and
[nautilus](https://i.imgur.com/nY6E3Df.png)

Comment: In the 'nautilus' screenshot, choose the last option: 'Type'. You will have to do that for every folder though. As you can see in your case the option 'A-Z' is selected.

Comment: Yes but I shouldn’t have to do that with the settings I made in dconf, and this doesn’t solve my original issue of the gnome application menu not sorting the folders first. Is it possible? Or do I have to number them like the post below so I can manually sort them.

Comment: I’m not trying to sort the files in nautilus, this is the gnome app menu that launches from my dock.

Comment: I just want to sort these folders before the apps in  [this](https://i.imgur.com/s0qpSZM.png) menu.