# Nautilus Files: How to use last modified sorting column?

Tags: nautilus

My Nautilus Files always reverts back to sort by "Name".

Is there any way to permanently save the configuration to sort by "Modified" instead?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default "sort by" to "type" in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252771/how-to-change-default-sort-by-to-type-in-nautilus) That questions a bit old, some of the settings might of changed.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get what I need with these two addition settings: `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order mtime` and `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-in-reverse-order true`